# Nagios check memory plugin

Tags: memory, plugins, nagios

Why doesn't Nagios have a check_memory as part of the initial set of plugins that come by default? Like check_http, check_load etc?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Nagios Plugins](http://nagiosplugins.org/node/2) the plugins in that project need to meet certain criteria, here is a statement from the FAQ:

> There are two types of plugins included in the distribution:
>
> - Plugins that are officially maintained by the nagios plugin
>     developer team
> - Plugins that are distributed in the contrib directory
>
> Sooner or later all the contrib plugins should be hosted at the
>   official 3rd Party Nagios plugin page Nagios Exchange
>
> Contrib plugins have to be installed manually. They are not affected
>   by the build process.
>
> Here is a list of the actively maintained Plugins:
>
> check_apt, check_breeze, check_by_ssh, check_clamd, check_cluster,
>   check_dhcp, check_dig, check_disk, check_disk_smb, check_dns,
>   check_dummy, check_file_age, check_flexlm, check_fping, check_ftp,
>   check_game, check_hpjd, check_http, check_icmp, check_ide_smart,
>   check_ifoperstatus, check_ifstatus, check_imap, check_ircd,
>   check_jabber, check_ldap, check_load, check_log, check_mailq,
>   check_mrtg, check_mrtgtraf, check_mssql, check_mysql,
>   check_mysql_query, check_nagios, check_netdns, check_nntp,
>   check_nntps, check_nt, check_ntp_peer, check_ntp_time, check_nwstat,
>   check_oracle, check_overcr, check_pgsql, check_ping, check_pop,
>   check_procs, check_radius, check_real, check_rpc, check_sensors,
>   check_simap, check_smtp, check_snmp, check_spop, check_ssh,
>   check_ssmtp, check_swap, check_tcp, check_time, check_udp, check_ups,
>   check_users, check_wave
>
> And these plugins are currently distributed in the contrib directory:
>
> check_adptraid, check_apache, check_apc_ups, check_appletalk,
>   check_arping, check_asterisk, check_axis, check_backup,
>   check_bgpstate, check_breeze, check_cluster, check_cluster2,
>   check_compaq_insight, check_cpqarray, check_digitemp,
>   check_dlswcircuit, check_dns_random, check_email_loop,
>   check_fan_cpq_present, check_fan_fsc_present, check_flexlm,
>   check_frontpage, check_hltherm, check_hprsc,
>   check_http-with-client-certificate, check_hw,
>   check_ica_master_browser, check_ica_metaframe_pub_apps,
>   check_ica_program_neigbourhood, check_inodes, check_inodes-freebsd,
>   check_ipxping, check_javaproc, check_joy, check_linux_raid,
>   check_lmmon, check_log2, check_lotus, check_maxchannels,
>   check_maxwanstate, check_mem, check_ms_spooler, check_mssql,
>   check_nagios, check_nagios_db, check_nagios_db_pg, check_netapp,
>   check_nmap, check_oracle_instance, check_oracle_tbs,
>   check_ora_table_space, check_pcpmetric, check_pfstate, check_qmailq,
>   check_rbl, check_remote_nagios_status, check_rrd_data, check_sap,
>   check_smart, check_smb, check_snmp_disk_monitor, check_snmp_printer,
>   check_snmp_process_monitor, check_snmp_procs, check_sockets,
>   check_temp_cpq, check_temp_fsc, check_timeout, check_traceroute,
>   check_traceroute-pure_perl, check_uptime, check_vcs, check_wave,
>   check_wins

As you can see there isn't an official check_memory plugin included in the maintained plugins, however you can find plugins that do support what you are looking for on [Naigos Exchange](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Uncategorized/Software/SNMP/SNMP-Memory/details).

Comment: How can we access contrib directory plugins ?

Answer (score 0):

if you install nagios-snmp-plugins from http://nagios.manubulon.com/ then you should have check_snmp_mem.pl and that will do the memory monitoring